# access to values in vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a Nx2 vector, each row in the vector is a coordinate in a matrix.
For example: vector that call Path look like this:

```
Path=[1 2;
 3 4;
 5 6;
 7 8;];
```

My question is how can I access the vector to take my x and y coordinates?
If I write Path(1) the answer is 1, and for Path(2) the answer is 3, But I want to take the pairs 1 2, then 3 4 etc..
Can I do it in a loop?
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This will give you every row one by one.

```
for i=1:size(Path,1)
    Path(i,:)
end
```

If you just want to plot the path, try:

```
plot(Path(:,1),Path(:,2))
```

Comment: Thank you, But how can I access to the elemants?
I want to draw the path, coordinate after coordinate, for this I run in a loop and I need to supply the x and y to plot function in each iteretion of the loop...
Thats why I want somthing like Path(1),Path(2)
Thanks

Comment: Ok I have manage, I just write plot(Path(i,1),Path(i,2)

Comment: Also note my edit in case you just want to plot the entire path.